# React native get installation date

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the installation date of my application on my user`s device.

Is it possible to get the date my application was installed on the user`s device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no React-native method to get that. But there is a third party module present [react-native-app-install-date](https://github.com/meenunegi/react-native-app-install-date). This module doesn't come up with any documentation. But you can refer [App.js](https://github.com/meenunegi/react-native-app-install-date/blob/master/App.js) file of the module and make required changes. This is not tested by me.

Another way is to write your own plugin. Refer [this](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-get-app-install-date-in-react-native-ba4519150478) and [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios).

Answer (score 0):

Package "react-native-app-install-date" will work and it gets the installation date with native code from iOS and Android.
right repo referring to npm package: https://github.com/quyenlt1812/react-native-app-install-date

npmjs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-install-date

**Other option** is to store it in localstorage. This will work as long as app's localstorage is not wiped. Good npm package for this is "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage". If wipe happens you need to save the date again and then it's not correct anymore. So this is not 100% bulletproof option.

npmjs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Store the timestamp, if it not already exists as the app starts.
Then you can check it whenever needed later from the localstorage.